# Multi page PHP form error

Tags: php, wordpress, session, post, get

Page 1's info is successfully transferring to page 2 however, after page 2 is filled and submitted, page 3 opens as a 404 error page.
I don't know what is wrong (am using Wordpress and page 3 does exist but won't open after page 2 is submitted).
You can check it live [here](http://testwebsitepage.club/offer/).
Page one is at `offer/`
page two is at `offer/details/`
page three is at `offer/details/results/`

So the code for page 1 is:-

```
<form action="details/" method="post">
    Loan Calculator
    <select name="loan_amount" class="form-inline" style="width:200px;">
        <option value="1000">$1,000 Loan</option>
        <option value="25000" selected="selected">$25,000 Loan</option>
    </select>
    <select name="loan_tenure" class="form-inline" style="width:125px;">
        <option value="4">4 Years</option>
        <option value="5" selected="selected">5 Years</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="form-inline">
</form>
```

Code for page 2 is:-

```
session_start();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}

echo '<form action="results/" method="post">';
echo '<strong>Who should we send this quote to?</strong><br>';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="loan_amount2" value="' . $_POST["loan_amount"] . '" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="loan_tenure2" value="' . $_POST["loan_tenure"] . '" />';
echo '<input style="width:320px; margin-left:16px; margin-top:15px;" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*"><br>';
echo '<input style="width:320px; margin-left:16px;" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*"><br>';
echo '<input style="width:320px; margin-bottom:7px; height:50px; padding-left:7px;" type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone*"><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Get My Monthly Repayments">';
echo '</form>';
```

Code for page 3 is:-

```
session_start();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: do you have page `results`?

Comment: yes, it is at http://testwebsitepage.club/offer/details/results/
if you open it directly, it opens just fine.

Comment: change this url `<form action="results" method="post">` and 2nd step try again?

Comment: Tried, still same problem. I don't understand how it could open the right page but display a 404 error and not display the page whereas the page opened directly with the url opens just fine.

Comment: print what? sorry how do you mean?

Comment: hold on, let me check that on xampp.

Comment: ok i just checked, and yes, the values of page 1 and page 2 are printing just fine on page 3.

Comment: page 1 is parent template of page 2 and page 2 is parent of page 3.

Comment: yes absolutely, worth a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake (Thanks to @vel). It is actually very silly.
In page 2 form code, name of an `input` field is given as `name` which is illegal because it is a special keyword.
That is what was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

use the hidden field

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="page_2_valid_0987" value="page_2_valid_0987" />';
```

in step 2

in you functions.php should be like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['page_2_valid_0987'])){
    store_values_of_page_two($_POST);
}

function store_values_of_page_two($_POST) { 
    session_start(); 

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value; 
    } 

    $newURL = site_url(); . "/offer/details/results/"; 
    wp_redirect( $newURL );
    exit;
}
```

Print the session in result page

```
session_start();

var_dump($_SESSION);
```